# How to push json item to array?

Tags: javascript

I have the following json:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Lat": 39.21988,
    "Lng": 9.124741,
    "Date": "01.01.2020",
    "Time": "08:54:00 AM",
    "Plastic": 0.156,
    "Metal": 0.321,
    "Paper": 0.098,
    "Glass": 0.085
  },
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Lat": 39.21988,
    "Lng": 9.124741,
    "Date": "01.01.2020",
    "Time": "10:15:23 AM",
    "Plastic": 0.078,
    "Metal": 0.652,
    "Paper": 0.085,
    "Glass": 0.078
  },
```

I tried:

```
    var str = JSON.stringify(<?php echo $contents; ?>, null, 2);
    $.each (str, function (i) {
      console.log(str[i]["lat"]);
    });
```

But I'm doing it wrong. I know I'm not pushing but the looping is wrong.

I need to loop over those items and I need `lat+lng` to be pushed to a single array like

```
const coords: ["lat, lng", "lat, lng"]
```

Comment: This sounds rather a PHP question than a JavaScript one to me.

Comment: @Ryuno-Ki why? The json is consumed from PHP but it's pure json now

Comment: @CalvinNunes I did, the last bit of code in the question

Comment: you need to do something like `arrayOfYours.push({lat: str[i]['lat'], lng: str[i]['lng']});`

Comment: @JDunken yes indeed but for some reason my looping is wrong

Comment: 'The JSON. stringify() method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string' that's not what you want, you need to keep it a json object, perhaps you wanted `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @JDunken I see, might you provide a code sample please? Someone mentioned it on an answer but didn't provide a code sample

Comment: it's as simple as `const jsonObject = JSON.parse(whateverTheResponseIsCalled);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207382/discussion-between-rob-m-and-jdunken).

Comment: @rob.m Because `<?php echo $contents; ?>` is PHP and `$.each` is no native JavaScript as well.
But I leave the answers to others now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
var jsonObj = [
      {
        "ID": 1,
        "Lat": 39.21988,
        "Lng": 9.124741,
        "Date": "01.01.2020",
        "Time": "08:54:00 AM",
        "Plastic": 0.156,
        "Metal": 0.321,
        "Paper": 0.098,
        "Glass": 0.085
      },
      {
        "ID": 1,
        "Lat": 39.21988,
        "Lng": 9.124741,
        "Date": "01.01.2020",
        "Time": "10:15:23 AM",
        "Plastic": 0.078,
        "Metal": 0.652,
        "Paper": 0.085,
        "Glass": 0.078
      }];

var coords = jsonObj.map(function(item) {
    return (item.Lat + "," + item.Lng);
});
console.log(coords); // ["39.21988,9.124741", "39.21988,9.124741"]
```

If you are having your JSON as a string, then you can use `JSON.parse("yourString")` to get your JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Stringify the JSON if you're going to iterate over it.

if anything you may want to use `JSON.parse` as it could be coming from PHP as a string.

something like this:

```
var array = <?php echo $contents; ?>;
/// or if it's coming as a string from php
var array = JSON.parse(<?php echo $contents; ?>);

array.forEach((thing) => {
  coords.push({thing['lat'], thing['lng']});
  console.log(thing.lat);
});
```

Comment: thanks, might you provide a code sample too please?

Comment: thanks, but it is giving me in console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['`

Comment: i confirm if it helps that the json is coming as a string from php

Comment: did you try with JSON.parse?

Comment: var str = JSON.parse(<?php echo $contents; ?>);
        str.forEach((i) => {
          coords.push({str[i]['lat'], str[i]['lng']});
        });

        console.log(str);

Comment: look again at my sample

Comment: still the same problem, had to accept the other answer as it was working, thanks a lot tho

Comment: yourJsonObject.forEach((i) => {yourArr.push({ lat: parseFloat(i.Lat), lng: parseFloat(i.Lng) }) }); I jumped over to the chat you initiated, but you didn't show up lil